# Obtaining value from textfield and inserting into API url

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have added a textfield with a TextEditingController

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  late TextEditingController nummerpladeController = new TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body:
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: nummerpladeController,
                onChanged: (str) {
                  setState(() {
                    str = nummerpladeController.text;
                  });
                },
              ),
              Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                  future: futureAlbum,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return new Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text("Registreringsnummer: ""${snapshot.data!.registration_number}"),
                          Text("Status: " "${snapshot.data!.status}"),
                          Text("Type: " "${snapshot.data!.type}"),
                          Text("Brug: " "${snapshot.data!.use}"),
                          Text("Første registrerings dato: ""${snapshot.data!.first_registration}"),
                          Text("Vin nummer: " "${snapshot.data!.vin}"),
                          Text("Mærke: " "${snapshot.data!.make}"),
                          Text("Model: " "${snapshot.data!.model}"),
                          Text("Variant: " "${snapshot.data!.variant}"),
                          Text("Model type: ""${snapshot.data!.model_type}"),
                          Text("Farve: " "${snapshot.data!.color}"),
                          Text("Bil type: " "${snapshot.data!.chasis_type}"),
                          Text("Brændstof: " "${snapshot.data!.fuel_type}"),
                          Text("Sidste syn: " "${snapshot.data!.date}"),
                          Text(nummerpladeController.text)
                        ],
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    }
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to use "Text(nummerpladeController.text)" and inserting the value from the textfield into the api url. Basically the input a numberplate where it take its value and insert it into the api url to get show the information from the api.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/(Value from textfield)'),
       headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

I don't know if it makes a difference but i have got Future at top and the class afterwards.

Comment: `fetchAlbum` is being called in initState which means before you type anything `fetchAlbum` will be called.

Comment: @nitishk72 how can i fix that so i can the value from textfield and insert it into api url?

Comment: when the api will be called? is there any button which will call the api?

Comment: @nitishk72 no i have not added a button, im new to flutter

Comment: @nitishk72 i have send you a email

Answer (score 0):

You have call the function after you have entered some value in your TextFormField then you have to pass the same value to your function after that it will return your value

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  late TextEditingController nummerpladeController = new TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body:
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: nummerpladeController,
                onChanged: (str) {
                  fetchAlbum(str);
                },
              ),
              Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                  future: futureAlbum,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return new Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text("Registreringsnummer: ""${snapshot.data!.registration_number}"),
                          Text("Status: " "${snapshot.data!.status}"),
                          Text("Type: " "${snapshot.data!.type}"),
                          Text("Brug: " "${snapshot.data!.use}"),
                          Text("Første registrerings dato: ""${snapshot.data!.first_registration}"),
                          Text("Vin nummer: " "${snapshot.data!.vin}"),
                          Text("Mærke: " "${snapshot.data!.make}"),
                          Text("Model: " "${snapshot.data!.model}"),
                          Text("Variant: " "${snapshot.data!.variant}"),
                          Text("Model type: ""${snapshot.data!.model_type}"),
                          Text("Farve: " "${snapshot.data!.color}"),
                          Text("Bil type: " "${snapshot.data!.chasis_type}"),
                          Text("Brændstof: " "${snapshot.data!.fuel_type}"),
                          Text("Sidste syn: " "${snapshot.data!.date}"),
                          Text(nummerpladeController.text)
                        ],
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    }
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Album> fetchAlbum(String str) async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/$str'),
       headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried pasting the code u provided but when i run the app its a red screen where it says: LateIntializerError: Field 'futureAlbum' has not been initialized.

Comment: i have fixed the problem, but now when i type something in the textfield it keeps showing a loading spinner and dosen't return the data from the API

Comment: this will show the data once you enter correct details in Textfield.

Comment: @Diwyanish im sure i have typed in the correct details but i have noticed something in the log. In the API url if i just type the numberplate in the url like this: ```https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/cz33849``` it will work, but when i type cz33849 in the textfield the errorlogs says: E/flutter ( 6773): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to load album
E/flutter ( 6773): #0      fetchAlbum (package:untitled2/main.dart:171:5)
E/flutter ( 6773): <asynchronous suspension>.

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: Thank you i would appreciate that

Comment: Actually the exception is because you have reached your limit of 100 requests

Comment: have you checked?